# How to perform mongoose aggregate operation in nestjs/mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregate, nestjs

I would like to perform an aggregate operation on mongoose subdocuments using nestjs/mongoose. But I couldn't find any resources on the internet on how to do that. For example:

```
{
  username: 'xyz',
  addresses: [
   {address: '1 street'},
   {address: '2 street'}
  ]
}

UserDoc.aggregate([
{$match: {username: 'xyz'}},
{$unwind: $addresses}
])
```

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee  The expected result is something like: addresses: [{username: 'xyz', addresses: [{address: '1 street'}]},{username: 'xyz', addresses: [{address: '2 street'}]}]. I am just unsure about how to do that with nestjs/mongoose

Comment: look at this working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cZcJ4JUmtJy)